# Is that sound or words?

Tags: manga

[image: uhh]

tell me please, is that sound or words :<

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I do think this question could be improved.  I think the main problem is that you haven't included any context at all.  Sure, I could guess "Maybe they're starting to say ドラゴンに乗って", but without any additional context all it is is a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Words. Hard to tell what the のっ is short for but presumably the context would make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Going by my observation skills; seeing as how the のっ is repeating itself, and appears to be floating above what I think is the shoulder of the character making the  のっ, I'm guessing it's a sound; or in the case of outer-character narration, it would be as Darius pointed out, words. Further context would greatly assist as far as figuring out which one it is.